# Access local html page from external servers

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a link from a webpage to a locally stored html file, at this point it is just for testing purposes, before I load the new content on to the website servers. I can't seem to get the link to open the html file. Is there any way I can do this, or is it just not an option?
Thanks all.

Comment: You'll need a development web environment such as WAMP, and port-forward port 80 on your router to point to your system.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your computer a server by using a service such as dynaip, that would make it accessible for creating links to your file from webservers on the internet.